# GCP Machine Instances Insert: RESOURCE_OPERATION_RATE_EXCEEDED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We're using the `@google-cloud/compute` library to do an `instancesClient.insert` using a machine image that we have.

We haven't bumped into this issue until recently where we tried creating ~200 VMs at the same time. Normally we've been able to do this, but we haven't done it exactly at the same time. (Maybe over 30 seconds to 5 minutes)

We began receiving these on the following error.

```
RESOURCE_OPERATION_RATE_EXCEEDED
Operation rate exceeded for resource 'projects/xxxx/global/machineImages/xxxx'. Too frequent operations from the source resource.
```

Some notes:

- In this particular instance, we're looking to start ~200 VMs
- We don't have this issue if we're starting them slightly staggered,
  say over a couple minutes
- We did make requests to start these in the same zone/region - BUT, we did not actually fill that zone/region successfully due to the OPERATION_RATE issue
- Is this associated with this? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/snapshot-best-practices#creating_new_zonal_persistent_disks_from_snapshots
- Don't think we exceeded these: https://cloud.google.com/compute/operations-quota

I can't find anything that speaks towards this specific issue. It doesn't appear that there's information on operation limits specifically towards `images`

Comment: The solution is simple. You must implement Expotential backoff and retry. ***Exponential backoff is a standard error handling strategy for network applications in which a client periodically retries a failed request with increasing delays between requests.***

Answer (score 1):

In this particular instance, we were trying to create new VMs based off of Machine Images. We had made many VMs, but it appears that this is a loosely enforced limit:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/create-instance-from-machine-image#restrictions

```
You can create at most 6 VMs from a source machine image in 60 minutes. If you exceed this limit, the instance create operation fails and returns an error similar to the following: 

 Operation rate exceeded for resource 'projects/test/global/machineImages/machine-image-1'.
 Too frequent operations from the source resource.

To create more VMs than the defined limit (6 VMs in 60 minutes), create additional machine images from the source VM or create short-lived machine images from the new VMs. You can then create the required number of VMs from the new machine images.
```

In order to come around this, we used custom images instead:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-custom

Custom Images are created by taking a snapshot of a VM's boot disk. They capture the entire state of the disk, including the operating system, applications, and data. Custom Images are more like snapshots of a specific disk at a point in time. They also have a different resource limitation.

This allows us to create as many VMs as we want.

Comment: Make sure you are creating snapshots from stopped VMs. Don't image live VMs.